# How to avoid BoxLayout expanding JPanels size?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have the following piece of code that creates three panels, a container panel, and two more panels that contain a label and an input field each:

```
    JPanel clientPanel = new JPanel();
    clientPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10, 25, 10, 25));
    clientPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(clientPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    JPanel cNamePanel = new JPanel();
    cNamePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cNamePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
    JLabel cNameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
    JTextField jtfNameLabel = new JTextField();
    jtfNameLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    JPanel cPhonePanel = new JPanel();
    cPhonePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    cPhonePanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    JLabel cPhoneLabel = new JLabel("Phone:");
    JTextField jtfPhoneLabel = new JTextField();
    jtfPhoneLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 20));

    cNamePanel.add(cNameLabel);
    cNamePanel.add(jtfNameLabel);
    cPhonePanel.add(cPhoneLabel);
    cPhonePanel.add(jtfPhoneLabel);

    clientPanel.add(cNamePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
    clientPanel.add(cPhonePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

With this piece of code, the result I get when I execute it is the following (I marked in green the container panel and gave a background color for each of its subpanels to see its dimensions):

[image]

As you can see, there's a huge gap between the "Name" panel and "Phone" panel which I would like to reduce, as I also want to add more panels such as those.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use more nested JPanels. You could use a JPanel that uses GidLayout with 1 column and variable number of rows, and place your name and phone panels in it, and then place this grid layout using JPanel into one that uses BorderLayout, at the BorderLayout.PAGE_START location, and then place *that* JPanel into this BoxLayout using JPanel....

Comment: The key is to experiment and play with your layouts to see what works best.

Comment: Generally, when you want to layout a form with a name, address, phone number, etc. labels, and text fields, you use a `GridBagLayout` and one `JPanel` to lay out the entire form.  Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74981333/i-am-trying-to-make-a-user-registration-page-my-code-runs-smoothly-but-my-final/74982433#74982433) I did for another person.

Comment: I agree with @GilbertLeBlanc. If you want to create an input form with labels and textfields, use GridBagLayout. Please check out my example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42256350/), an example that can create any grid of input fields desired, based on an array of string. Also, avoid constraining the preferred size of a Swing component and in particular, ***never*** constrain the size or preferred size of a text component such as a JTextField or JTextArea. Instead, set their column properties, and for the latter, also the row property. Otherwise the text component will not work correctly.